# DHL Tracking API with webhooks and how to get early access

Tags: push-notification, webhooks, dhl

There's a DHL [developer support article](https://support-developer.dhl.com/en/support/solutions/articles/47001224414-is-there-an-api-where-there-are-push-notifications-updates-for-tracking-shipments-) about their upcoming 'push notifications' tracking API. I think webhooks might be a clearer term.
The article invites developers to contact DHL support for early access. Their reply to my request included a link to their new [webhook tracking API documentation](https://developer.dhl.com/api-reference/shipment-tracking-unified-push#get-started-section/):

> Thanks for your interest in DHL. Here's the link to the API
> documentation: Shipment Tracking - Unified - Push. Please read the
> documentation carefully as it explains how to request access to the
> API, what services the API offers, and how to use it (under the
> "Reference Docs" section).

But I received an 'access denied' message when visiting the link. When I asked DHL support to grant access to the new webhook documentation:

> I'm getting access denied when visiting the provided link for the API
> documentation. Maybe access needs granted for my account?

Then they seemed to reverse their decision to grant access:

> My apologies. Shipment Tracking - Unified - Push API is in the
> development state now. We will let you know once it's available.

Has anyone successfully received access to the new webhooks (push) API for DHL tracking? And if so, how?